# writing to a file with an uncertain filename

Tags: c++, file, input, output, ofstream

I've given an assignment where I need to take some input from a file named like: "filename.s" and my code should write the output to a file named "filename.m". here's my code but i'm having compiling issues when i try to open the file as `outfile.open(out);`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  readFile(argv);
  int x=0;
  compile(x);
  mystring += "halt";
  cout << mystring<< endl;
  string out = argv[1];
  out.resize(out.size()-1);
  out += "m";
  ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open(out);
  outfile << mystring;
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Anyone knows what might be the issue? Because it does compile when i give an argument like this: `outfile.open("blah.m");`thanks for your replies.

Comment: I suggest you edit the code and add the declarations for all your variables first.

Comment: Do you mean that you have compilation errors? In that case you should edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use an older compiler without C++11, so the line

```
outfile.open(out);
```

fails to compile since ni C++98 open accepts character pointers only no std::strings. Change the line to

```
outfile.open(out.c_str());
```

and it should compile

Comment: worked. thanks! also, do you know how to update g++ in ubuntu 13.10 to c++11?

Comment: @AtakanArıkan You add the flag `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
outfile.open(out.c_str());
```

In C++98, the parameter of `open()` is `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution, but rather specific to this case:

```
size_t pos = strlen(argv[1]) - 1;
argv[1][pos] = 'm';

std::ofstream out(argv[1]); // Easier to just create the stream already opened.
```